# Mac App enterprise distribution outside AppStore with MapKit

Tags: macos, mac, mac-appstore, enterprise

Either I'm being stupid (probably true) or there is hadly any documentatio to address the question:

How can I distribute an Enterprise Mac app which uses MapKit?

Background: We have built an iOS app and server which has a Mac app to act as the admin dashboard. Obviously the client doesn't want the OSX app in the app store. It wouldn't be relavant to anyone except their admins and might even attract hostile users. I've managed to make developer signed releases for their team which work in all respects except they won't display maps.

I was hoping for something like the iOS enterprise store for Mac apps but I can't find it and it seems that MapKit is limited to AppStore releases.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, Apple would offer a Mac equivalent to the [iOS Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/). Sadly, this is not currently offered.

### Contact Apple

Contact Apple through [Developer Technical Support](https://developer.apple.com/contact/) or through the [Mac App Store](https://www.apple.com/support/mac/app-store/contact/). They should be able to suggest the best approach – which Apple will support. At the very least, it will help prove demand for the capability.

#### Ad Hoc Distribution

Depending on your situation, you may be able to use [ad hoc distribution](http://www.imore.com/install-beta-mac-app-store-apps-provisioning-profiles). It is designed for testing and imposes limits on the number of computers involved.

Answer (score 0):

Watch this video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/705/

It provides an overview of the Apple Enterprise Developer and B2B distribution programs. To become an Enterprise Developer you need a DUNS number and willingness to pay $299/year for the Enterprise Developer programs.